# HOpenGL - OpenGL window remains minimized

Tags: opengl, haskell, glut, ubuntu-10.10

Following some well-known [OpenGL Haskell tutorial](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/OpenGLTutorial1), I've made my first HOpenGL program. Here's the code:

```
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL
import Graphics.UI.GLUT

main = do
  (progname, _) <- getArgsAndInitialize
  createWindow "Hello World"
  displayCallback $= clear [ ColorBuffer ]
  mainLoop
```

It compiles and runs, but window is simply not shown - upon "maximize" command, you can see it for some fractions of second, and then it minimizes. May this issue be connected to my ATI Radeon video card?

P.S. OS is Ubuntu 10.10, program compiled with GHC 7.0.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems solved, upon installing haskell-platform from official repo. Which library was lacking, still remains mystery to me, and I'm not sure I want to dig into this.
Trying to fetch all missing Haskell libs on your own is BDSM.

**Edit:** Window minimizes only if run from terminal. All works fine (+/-) if run from nautilus.